# How can I transpose a list of documents in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a document like:

```
{
   "_id": "6345e01473144cec0073ea95",
   "results": [
        {"total_cost": 10, "total_time": 20},
        {"total_cost": 30, "total_time": 40}
   ]
}
```

And I want to 'transpose' the list of documents to get:

```
{
    "total_cost": [10, 30],
    "total_time": [20, 40]
}
```

How can I find an object by ID, and then apply a transform on a list of documents with a mongo aggregation?

Every question/answer I have seen doing this has been for multiple documents, however this is for a single document with a list field.

(I am using MongoEngine/Pymongo so I have included the python tag)

Comment: Why do you want to do it with a mongo aggregation? Mongo aggregations are useful to do server-side aggregation, but I don't see how it would be better here than just read the document in python and transform it client-side?

Comment: @GeertPt I need to do it as part of an even larger aggregation, which I would rather do all server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply access the fields with dot notation. You can think the projection of the fields as an individual array, i.e. `results.total_cost` is an array with content [10, 30]

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      total_cost: "$results.total_cost",
      total_time: "$results.total_time"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ia4WmtIGbkN) with your reference.